# Wrong number when reference inside algorithm

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms, algorithmic

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{algorithm}[tb]
    \caption{Algorithm}
    \label{alg}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \STATE blalblabla \label{cond1}
        \STATE blablabla \label{cond2}
        \STATE  return to step \ref{cond2}.
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

As you see it gives "return to step 1" (instead of 2)

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable! Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a label and a ref, you need to compile your document twice. Otherwise an error may occur.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[tb]
    \caption{Algorithm}
    \label{alg}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \STATE blalblabla \label{cond1}
        \STATE blablabla \label{cond2}
        \STATE  return to step \ref{cond2}.
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Which gives when compilied twice:

[image]

Comment: In a new latex file it works for me, but not in the original one. Any idea why ??

Comment: @user96784 You may have used the same label twice for example. You can try to remove the aux too

Comment: No, also tried to remove aux, still the same problem.

Comment: @user96784 well, without a proper MWE it will be hard to answer the question then